# I Can only hear out of the left side of my razer kraken pro neon

Tags: laptop, headphones

I can only hear out of the left ear and I tried my headset on another computer works fine and then I try another pair of headphones on my computer works fine. PLZPLZPLZ HELP

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking at the balance settings?
They might be set to go all left for your headset

[image]